# access to record params with ActiveRecord relation number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to get a record in DB by having these two lines in one of my models:

```
a = Arel::Table.new(:receivers)
e = Receiver.where(a[:name].matches('%afsane%'))
```

In my receivers table I have a row in which the name column equals to "afsane".I want to have that row's id in my model.
but by printing the e in my model I've got this :

```
"========#<Receiver::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0056094261eff8>============"
```

which gives the relation number but no params.
When I run them in rails console I got this response:

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Receiver id: 2, name: "afsane", created_at: "2016-09-27 09:24:16", updated_at: "2016-10-09 10:10:02">]>
```

I managed to have this in my model But I couldn't .

ps:Using Rails 5.

**Have any Ideas ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the variable `a` looks like but the variable `e` **is** a collection.
`where` returns a collection which means you will have to iterate through `e` in order to pull out some data.

Like so:

```
e.each do |data|
  data.name
end
```

If you want to return only 1 result then you can simply do the following:

```
e = Receiver.where(a[:name].matches('%afsane%')).limit(1)
```

Note: I've kept the answer simple but there are more elegant solutions to this so I recommend you reading the [ActiveRecord Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Comment: Thank you.You were right about the limit.I fixed the code with first which gives the first match column.